# Use stored procedure for search method

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, asp.net-core

I started with ASP.Net Core 2.0, I'm trying to rewrite a method `GetAll` by search use stored procedure. Here is method search:

```
public async Task<List<DepartmentTypeDto>> SearchDepartmentType()
{
    EnsureConnectionOpen();

    using (var command = CreateCommand("CM_DEPT_GROUP_Search", CommandType.StoredProcedure))
    {
        using (var dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
                List<DepartmentTypeDto> result = new List<DepartmentTypeDto>();

                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    DepartmentTypeDto departmentTypeDto = new DepartmentTypeDto
                    {
                        GROUP_ID = dataReader["GROUP_ID"].ToString(),
                        GROUP_CODE = dataReader["GROUP_CODE"].ToString(),
                        GROUP_NAME = dataReader["GROUP_NAME"].ToString(),
                        NOTES = dataReader["NOTES"].ToString(),
                        RECORD_STATUS = dataReader["RECORD_STATUS"].ToString(),
                        MAKER_ID = dataReader["MAKER_ID"].ToString(),
                        CREATE_DT = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader["CREATE_DT"]),
                        AUTH_STATUS = dataReader["AUTH_STATUS"].ToString(),
                        CHECKER_ID = dataReader["CHECKER_ID"].ToString(),
                        APPROVE_DT = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader["APPROVE_DT"]),
                        AUTH_STATUS_NAME = dataReader["AUTH_STATUS_NAME"].ToString(),
                        RECORD_STATUS_NAME = dataReader["RECORD_STATUS_NAME"].ToString()
                    };
                }
                return result;   
            }
        }
}
```

Here is the service:

```
public async Task<PagedResultDto<GetDepartmentTypeForView>> GetAll(GetAllDepartmentTypesInput input)
{
     var filteredDepartmentTypes = _departmentTypeRepository.SearchDepartmentType();

     var query = (from o in filteredDepartmentTypes
                  select new GetDepartmentTypeForView() { DepartmentType = ObjectMapper.Map<DepartmentTypeDto>(o) });

     var totalCount = await query.CountAsync();

     var departmentTypes = await query
            .OrderBy(input.Sorting ?? "departmentType.id asc")
            .PageBy(input)
            .ToListAsync();

     return new PagedResultDto<GetDepartmentTypeForView>(totalCount, departmentTypes);
}
```

But I get an error:

> `Task<List<DepartmentTypeDto>>` does not contain a definition for `Select`

Does anyone know what I should do? I work on Asp.Net Zero.

Comment: Before `_departmentTypeRepository.SearchDepartmentType()` try to put `await` keyword.

Comment: `I started with ASP.Net Core 2.0` So, why don't you use Entity Framework? You can take a tour here: [Get started with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows)

Comment: @TânNguyễn sếp bảo làm cách này anh :D. I use FromSql and It works. Btw Hope to receive your help in the future if it possible

Answer (score 0):

I changed my search method

```
public IQueryable<DepartmentTypeView> SearchDepartmentType(GetAllDepartmentTypesInput input, int top)
    {
        try
        {
            var GROUP_FILTER = input.Filter;
            var GROUP_CODE = input.GROUP_CODEFilter;
            var GROUP_NAME = input.GROUP_NAMEFilter;
            var AUTH_STATUS = input.AUTH_STATUSFilter;

            var result = Context.Query<DepartmentTypeView>().FromSql($"EXEC CM_DEPT_GROUP_Search @p_GROUP_FILTER = {GROUP_FILTER}, @p_GROUP_CODE={GROUP_CODE}, @p_GROUP_NAME={GROUP_NAME}, @p_AUTH_STATUS={AUTH_STATUS}, @p_TOP={top}");

            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and in the service, I call that function

`var filteredDepartmentTypes = _departmentTypeRepository.SearchDepartmentType(input,100);`

I also create new class to keep the result and don't forget to map that class with DTO class

`configuration.CreateMap<DepartmentTypeView, DepartmentTypeDto>();`

It works for me.